# How to save one2many field in set_values method odoo 14

Tags: odoo, setvalue, odoo-14, one2many

I am using odoo 14 and added one2many field in 'res.config.settings'. But this field value show false when save this res.config.settings form.

Below is my code:-

```
class ProjectResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    hide_export_field = fields.One2many('export.hide', 'res_id', string='Hide Field')


    def set_values(self):
        super(ProjectResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        IrDefault = self.env['ir.default'].sudo()
        IrDefault.set('res.config.settings', 'hide_export_field', self.hide_export_field.ids)


class ExportHideFields(models.Model):
    _name = "export.hide"

    res_id = fields.Integer(string="Resend wizard")
    model_ids = fields.Many2one('ir.model', string='Model')
    field_for_hide = fields.Many2many('ir.model.fields', string='Field For Hide')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implement the getter ?

Comment: Hi Danimar, don't understand what you suggested?

Answer (score 3):

The Odoo model `res.config.settings` can't have **One2many** fields or it shouldn't. Also, to display values in views, you must inherit the `get_param` method and add your field to the response.

```py
from ast import literal_eval


class ProjectResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    hide_export_field = fields.Many2many('export.hide', string='Hide Field')

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ProjectResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        get_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param
        hide_export_field = get_param('hide_export_field', '[]')
        hide_export_field = [(6, 0, literal_eval(hide_export_field))]
        res.update(hide_export_field=hide_export_field)
        return res

    def set_values(self):
        res = super(ProjectResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        set_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param
        set_param('hide_export_field', self.hide_export_field.ids)
        return res


class ExportHideFields(models.Model):
    _name = "export.hide"

    res_id = fields.Integer(string="Resend wizard")
    model_ids = fields.Many2one('ir.model', string='Model')
    field_for_hide = fields.Many2many('ir.model.fields', string='Field For Hide')
```

Comment: Hi @Tiki, Thanks for reply. I tried this but its not working.

Comment: Its working well in many2many. But why requirement related to one2many.
can we have option like: 
IrDefault.set('export.hide', 'hide_export_field', self.hide_export_field.ids)